# URL encoding of the double quote

Tags: javascript, php, html

I know that the double quote character is not allowed in the url and it is encoded as `%22` and this is done with **utf-8 encoding** . But what happens if i build a browser which does not perform url encoding and queries with the double quotes itself as it is permitted in the utf-8 encoding scheme. for example: `www.google.com/"a"`. Moreover what would happen to the url parsing script in the server when it encounters a double quote?

Comment: Can probably handle that with `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: I don't see how quotes can be a problem. The only reason that quotes are considered special characters is that URIs are often used in environments where quotes are delimiters. `href="/%22quoted%22"`, things like that. And I don't see differences in how quotes are handled if I type them as `"` or `%22`. I don't think it's the browser that does the translation there.

Comment: Real special characters, such as `/` or `#`, do need special attention though.

Comment: The premise of this question is flawed. `%22` is URL Escaping, and is unrelated to UTF-8.

Comment: No matter if you build a non-standard web browser. Servers like Apache do unescape (decode) url before processing them. So what's the point if you send a cooked food to a Cook? Security? No. You just don't follow standard and make errors for yourself :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you're passing invalid URI to the server, the server may respond with `HTTP 400 Bad Request` status, but may not. Different servers have different behavior on this. For example, the Apache 2.4 servers responds with `403 Forbidden`. It seems they recognize it as attempt of SQL-injection and suppress it immediately. The nginx servers responds with `404 Not Found`.

You don't need to build a browser which doesn't perform URL encoding to check. You can perform this query from simple telnet program which goes as a part of most operating systems (but may not be installed by default). If it's installed, you just need to execute `telnet www.google.com 80` in terminal window, paste following 2 lines:

```
GET /"a" HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

and press Enter twice. You will get response with `404 Not Found`. If you do the same with stackoverflow.com the response will be `400 Bad Request`.